# What are the semantics of parentheses in this in python expression?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This python statement gives the expected value when I wrap each shift with parentheses, otherwise it gives 0 :

```
Coef = ((0xFF&resp[0])<<24) + ((0xFF&resp[1])<<16) + ((0xFF&resp[2])<<8) +(0xFF&resp[3])) #OK

Coef = (0xFF&resp[0])<<24 + (0xFF&resp[1])<<16 + (0xFF&resp[2])<<8 +0xFF&resp[3]) #NOK
```

From my point of view as a C developer, having in mind that both *Coef* and *resp* are *unsigned ints* this statements should be equivalent.

My guess is that Python is confused about the type of the var when the parenthesis are absent.

Comment: Parentheses don't affect types, they just override operator precedence.

Comment: I would replace your C-level code by: *import struct; Coef=struct.unpack(">L", resp[:4])*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing to do with types; `+` has a higher precedence than `<<`. (This is also the case in C.) Your expression is parsed as:

```
((0xFF & resp[0])
    << (24 + (0xFF & resp[1]))
    << (16 + (0xFF & resp[2]))
    << (8 + 0xFF & resp[3]))
```

Also, if `resp` is a `bytes` (there’s a good chance it *should* be), you can just:

```
int.from_bytes(resp[:4], 'big')
```

If you *have* to use Python 2 for some reason, [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) can do the same job:

```
Coef, = struct.unpack('>I', resp[:4])
```

Comment: *from_bytes* is not available in Python 2.x, for an alternative see my comment to question.

Comment: @guidot: Oh, I missed that this was Python 2.7. Would recommend that the OP upgrade.